# How could I make a RecyclerView smoother?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-recyclerview, adapter

I am writing a sports application.I have to show all the games in a list in this application.
previously I used `ListView`, but now I use `RecyclerView` and its speed is better, but it's still not quite smooth and well.

How is it possible to make this better and smoother?

```
public class RecyclerAdapterMatch extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapterMatch.CustomViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<String> ls = new ArrayList<>();

private LayoutInflater mInflater;

Context con;
boolean page_info_know;
String tv_stat;

String[][] weeks = {{"اول", "دوم", "سوم", "چهارم", "پنجم", "ششم", "هفتم", "هشتم", "نهم", "دهم", "یازدهم", "دوازدهم", "سیزدهم", "چهاردهم", "پانزدهم", "شانزدهم", "هفدهم", "هجدهم", "نوزدهم", "بیستم", "بیست و یکم", "بیست و دوم", "بیست و سوم", "بیست و چهارم", "بیست و پنجم", "بیست و ششم", "بیست و هفتم", "بیست و هشتم", "بیست و نهم", "سی‌ام", "سی و یکم", "سی و دوم", "سی‌ و سوم", "سی و چهارم", "سی و پنجم", "سی و ششم", "سی و هفتم", "سی و هشتم", "سی و نهم", "چهلم"},
        {"رده‌بندی", "فینال", "نیمه‌نهایی", "یک چهارم", "یک هشتم", "یک شانزدهم نهایی", "۱/۳۲ نهایی", "۱/۶۴ نهایی"},
        {"یک", "دو", "سه", "چهار", "پنج", "شش", "هفت", "هشت", "نه", "ده", "یازده", "دوازده", "سیزده", "چهارده", "پانزده", "شانزده", "هفده", "هجده", "نوزده", "بیست"}};


public RecyclerAdapterMatch(Context con) {//}, ArrayList<String> ls) {
    this.con = con;
    //this.ls = ls;
}

public void addItem(Object object) {
    ls.add( object.toString() );
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (ls.get( position ).contains( "LeagueId" ))
        return 0;
    else return 1;
}

@Override
public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i/*in position nist*/) {

    CustomViewHolder leagueHolder = null;
    View v = null;


    try {

        if (i == 0) {
            v = LayoutInflater.from( viewGroup.getContext() ).inflate( R.layout.ly_row_league, viewGroup, false );

        } else {

            v = LayoutInflater.from( viewGroup.getContext() ).inflate( R.layout.row_result, viewGroup, false );

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    return new CustomViewHolder( v );

}

public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {

    try {
        JSONObject js=new JSONObject( ls.get( position ) );

        if (js.has( "LeagueId" )) {

            holder.league_name.setTypeface( AppConfig.getFont( con ) );
            holder.league_enter.setTypeface( AppConfig.getFontMaterial( con ) );
            holder.league_enter.setText( "\uf141" );

            switch (js.getInt( "Type" )) {
                case 0:
                    holder.league_name.setText( js.getString( "LeagueName" ) );
                    break;
                case 1:
                    holder.league_name.setText( js.getString( "LeagueName" ) + " | هفته " + weeks[js.getInt( "Type" ) - 1][js.getInt( "Week" ) - 1] );
                    break;
                case 2:
                    holder.league_name.setText( js.getString( "LeagueName" ) + " | مرحله " + weeks[js.getInt( "Type" ) - 1][js.getInt( "Week" ) - 1] );
                    break;
                default:
                    holder.league_name.setText( js.getString( "LeagueName" ) + " | گروه " + weeks[js.getInt( "Type" ) - 1][js.getInt( "Week" ) - 1] );
                    break;
            }


            int League_Type = js.getInt( "Type" );
            if (League_Type == 0) {
                holder.rel_league.setClickable( false );
            }

            holder.line_league.setBackgroundColor( Color.parseColor( "#" + js.getString( "Color" ) ) );

            page_info_know = js.getBoolean( "PageInfo" );

        } else {

            holder.txt_time.setTypeface( AppConfig.getFontLightNumFa( con ) );
            holder.txt_homeName.setTypeface( AppConfig.getFontBold( con ) );
            holder.txt_guestName.setTypeface( AppConfig.getFontBold( con ) );
            holder.txt_homeName.setText( js.getString( "HostName" ) );
            holder.txt_guestName.setText( js.getString( "GuestName" ) );

            holder.txt_RT.setTextSize( 12 );
            holder.txt_RT.setTypeface( AppConfig.getFont( con ) );

            holder.txt_date.setTypeface( AppConfig.getFont( con ) );

            ////////
            if (js.getInt( "Status" ) == 1) {

                AlphaAnimation alpha = new AlphaAnimation( 0, 1 );
                alpha.setDuration( 500 );
                alpha.setRepeatCount( Animation.INFINITE );
                alpha.setRepeatMode( Animation.REVERSE );
                holder.txt_live.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                holder.txt_live.setAnimation( alpha );
                holder.txt_live.setTypeface( AppConfig.getFont( con ) );
                holder.img_live.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                holder.img_live.setAnimation( alpha );

                holder.txt_time.setText( String.format( new Locale( "fa", "IR" ), "%d", js.getInt( "GuestGoal" ) ) + " - " + String.format( new Locale( "fa", "IR" ), "%d", js.getInt( "HostGoal" ) ) );

            } else if (js.getInt( "Status" ) == 2) {
                holder.txt_time.setText( String.format( new Locale( "fa", "IR" ), "%d", js.getInt( "GuestGoal" ) ) + " - " + String.format( new Locale( "fa", "IR" ), "%d", js.getInt( "HostGoal" ) ) );

            } else if (js.getInt( "Status" ) == 0) {

                StringBuilder time = new StringBuilder( js.getString( "Time" ).replace( "0", "۰" ).replace( "1", "۱" ).replace( "2", "۲" ).replace( "3", "۳" ).replace( "4", "۴" ).replace( "5", "۵" ).replace( "6", "۶" ).replace( "7", "۷" ).replace( "8", "۸" ).replace( "9", "۹" ) );
                time.insert( 2, ":" );
                holder.txt_time.setText( time.toString() );

            } else if (js.getInt( "Status" ) == 3) {
                holder.rel_tv_status.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                holder.txt_RT.setText( "لغو شده" );
            }

            tv_stat = js.getString( "RT" );

            if (page_info_know == false) {

                if (tv_stat == null || tv_stat.trim().length() == 0 || tv_stat.contains( "null" )) {
                    holder.rel_tv_status.setVisibility( View.GONE );
                } else {
                    holder.rel_tv_status.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                    holder.txt_RT.setText( tv_stat );
                }
            } else {
                holder.rel_tv_status.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                holder.txt_RT.setText( tv_stat );
                StringBuilder time = new StringBuilder( String.format( new Locale( "fa", "IR" ), "%d", js.getInt( "Date" ) ) );
                time.insert( 4, "/" );
                time.insert( 7, "/" );
                holder.txt_date.setText( time.toString() );
            }

            if (js.getString( "IsVideo" ).contains( "true" ) /*|| js.getString( "IsVideo" ).equals("null")*/) {
                holder.text_info.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                holder.text_info.setTypeface( AppConfig.getFontMaterial( con ) );
                holder.text_info.setText( "\uf40d" );
            } else {
                holder.text_info.setVisibility( View.GONE );
            }

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (ls != null) {
        return ls.size();
    }
    return 0;
}

static class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


    protected TextView txt_homeName, txt_guestName, txt_time, txt_RT, txt_live, league_name, league_enter, txt_date, text_info;
    protected RelativeLayout rel_tv_status, rel_league;
    protected ImageView img_live, img_league;
    protected LinearLayout line_league;

    public CustomViewHolder(View view) {
        super( view );
        txt_homeName = view.findViewById( R.id.textView10 );
        txt_guestName = view.findViewById( R.id.textView9 );
        txt_time = view.findViewById( R.id.textView3 );
        rel_tv_status = view.findViewById( R.id.tv_status_rel );

        txt_RT = view.findViewById( R.id.textView170 );
        txt_live = view.findViewById( R.id.textView74 );
        img_live = view.findViewById( R.id.imageView65 );
        league_name = view.findViewById( R.id.textView160 );
        league_enter = view.findViewById( R.id.textView161 );
        img_league = view.findViewById( R.id.imageView69 );
        line_league = view.findViewById( R.id.league_line_color );
        rel_league = view.findViewById( R.id.line_league_all );
        txt_date = view.findViewById( R.id.textView174 );
        text_info = view.findViewById( R.id.textView176 );

    }
}


}
```

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to try to [solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @TouhidulIslam I know that I should search for that first and I did it
but I couldn't found any solution

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues that catches the eye

1.Don't create new object inside on `onBindViewHolder`

For example, Move this below portion to `RecyclerAdapterMatch(Context con)`

```
AlphaAnimation alpha = new AlphaAnimation( 0, 1 );
alpha.setDuration( 500 );
alpha.setRepeatCount( Animation.INFINITE );
alpha.setRepeatMode( Animation.REVERSE );
```

2.Don't create typeface every time you set a font, rather, make a font on activity or adapter initialization, make it static and use it every other call. 
For Example, Replace `holder.league_name.setTypeface( AppConfig.getFont( con ));` with `holder.league_name.setTypeface(staticFontName);`

3.Don't set text the same text programmatically if it is always applies to textview, rather set it on xml.

Repalce `league_enter.setText( "\uf141" )` with

```
<TextView 
     android:id="+@textView161"
     android:text="\uf141"
```